# Accessing SOAP Webservice Problems

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, https, wsdl

at the moment Iam working as a working student at a Software Company and I got the task to setup a client who works with a webservice from a third party (only have a wsdl-, xsd file and user certificate).

I read a lot about Webservices in the last time and I did a lot of tutorials, but I did not manage to connect to the Server and make a simple test request.

I have a Windowsform Application an added a Service reference to the project via the physical path of the wsdl document. From this the generated proxy classes.

The wsdl and xsd file you can find here [https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qgopygt9gtbhwq6/AADHp8k1ktfNrzMVKCjQ0EsPa?dl=0][1]

```
        EndpointAddress ea = new EndpointAddress("https://212.62.77.106:9443/hapwebservices/secure_routed/dms");

        DMSServiceClient client = new DMSServiceClient(new BasicHttpsBinding(), ea);

        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\Users\myName\Desktop\DMS-test-2016.p12", "privateKey");

        client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = cert;

        Header header = new Header();
        header.InputTime = DateTime.Now;
        header.SystemId ="TheSystemID";
        header.OrganisationId = "TheOrganisationID";
        header.Password = "Password";
        header.OrganisationName = "Oraganisation";
        header.InterfaceVersion="3.0";
        header.DMSVersion = "1";
        header.DMSName = "DMSNAME";

        DateTime datetime = DateTime.Now;

        client.test(header, ref datetime);
```

Above you see my Code to invoke the test Method. But I alway get the exception that the Server Certificate is probably not configured correctly with HTTP.SYS. Another Reason is a mismatch from Client and Server.

Can you help me with this issue? Have I set up the proxy classes correctly?

Many thanks in advance!

Regards Lars

Comment: Could you post the whole exception?

Comment: General Error Occurred System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while making the HTTP request

This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.